# React.js: how to map through nested arrays

Tags: reactjs

Lets say I have an array of objects (`myContacts`), In React I can map through each object of the array to get its `item` and `index`. I can use the item[key] to get it's value but what if its value is another array?.. how can I map through that?

this is what I'm trying:

```
const myContacts = [
   {
     name: 'John',
     hobbies: ['swimming', 'skateboard', 'TV']
   },
   {
     name: 'Sarah',
     hobbies: ['Cooking'],
   },
   {
     name: 'Cindy',
     hobbies: ['Shopping', 'Running'],
   },
];
 
function MyPeeps({ myContacts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {myContacts.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{item.name}</p>
            {item.hobbies &&
              <ul>
                //if there is a hobbies array for this person, then list each as an `li`
              </ul>
            }
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Use `map` again?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can just do the same:

```
<ul>{item.hobbies.map(i => <li>i</li>)}</ul>
```

But a better idea could be to create a `Contact` component to avoid excessive nesting, then delegate to it:

```
<div key={index}>
    <Contact item={item} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `item.hobbies.length > 0` if you're sure that the hobbies array is always present.

```js
function MyPeeps({ myContacts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {myContacts.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{item.name}</p>
            {item.hobbies && (
              <ul>
                {item.hobbies.map((hobby) => (
                  <li key={hobby}>{hobby}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using map() function: You can use the built-in map() function in JavaScript to iterate through a nested array in React. The map() function takes a callback function as its argument, which is invoked for each element in the array. You can use the callback function to access the nested arrays and their elements.
2. Using recursion: You can also use recursion to iterate through a nested array in React. In this approach, you create a function that calls itself when it encounters a nested array. This function can then access the elements of the nested arrays and return the desired result.

Here is an example of using map() to iterate through a nested array in React:

```
const nestedArray = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {nestedArray.map((innerArray) => (
        <div>
          {innerArray.map((element) => (
            <div>{element}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is an example of using recursion to iterate through a nested array in React:

```
const nestedArray = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {recursiveMap(nestedArray)}
    </div>
  );
}

function recursiveMap(arr) {
  return arr.map((element) => {
    if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      return recursiveMap(element);
    }
    return <div>{element}</div>;
  });
}
```

Note: The above examples are just for demonstration and may not work as it is if you copy-paste it to your code. You need to make some modifications according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
  {item.hobbies.length && (
          <ul>
            {item.hobbies.map((hobby) => (
              <li key={hobby}>{hobby}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Thanks, for your suggestion, I will keep it remember.

Answer (score -1):

```
      { 
       item.hobbies.length>0 &&
          <ul>
              item.hobbies.map((hobby,index)=>{
              return <li key={index}>{hobby}</li>
               })
          </ul>
        }
```